# C: Globally define multidimensional char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, global, multidimensional-array

What I have to do is: Read x strings s_1 ... s_x of defined max. length l=1000000 and store them. The variable x is given as an input and the representation should be globally defined.

How I want to do it is:

1. Globally define the pointer to a pointer to char:

   ```
   char** S;
   ```
2. Locally, after reading x from input, allocate space for x pointers to char:

   ```
   S = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*x);
   ```
3. Locally allocating space for each single string s_i and reading the string into the allocated space:

   ```
   while(i<x){
       S[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*1000000);
       scanf("%s",S[i]);
       i++;
   }
   ```

When I try to access

```
    S[0][0]
```

it gives a memory access error. Any ideas? Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I printed the array and it worked fine so the problem is indeed in the accessing code. Here it is: anyone can see what's the problem? Because I can't...

```
    makeBinary(){

        printf("inside makeBinary()\n");

        S_b = malloc(sizeof(int)*1000000*x);
        length = malloc(sizeof(int)*x);
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(j=0;j<1000000;j++){ printf("1\n");  
                if(S[i][j]=='\0'){  printf("2\n");
                    length[i] = j; 
                        break;                  
                }else{  
                    S_b[i][j] = S[i][j]-96;     printf("3\n");      
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
```

It prints '1' then it crashes. I know the code is far from optimal but for now I would just like to solve the problem first. Thanks!

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` (that may actually be your problem if you didn't inlcude `<stdlib.h>`). Is `S = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*t);` the `t` a typo here, or in the actual code? If the latter, that could also be the problem.

Comment: Can you show the code that's trying to access S[0][0]?

Comment: Why on earth do you cast a result of malloc explicitly?

Comment: Haha I casted it after I saw this on some other apparently stupid website. I had it different before...

Comment: and t should be x of course sorry

Comment: oh so smart - the substractions doesnt' work sry guys :(

Comment: actually in the allocation of S_b I wish I could just delete the question :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things going on:
changed the strange casting malloc thing that works but is icky.
 
Also you shouldn't use sprintf to copy memory...
I wouldn't always allocate the max.
you can alloc the correct amount, `strlen()+1`... make sure to 0 pad the end... something like:

```
int t = 100;
char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(char*)*t);
S = &buffer;

for( int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
    char * somestring = __FILE__;
    size_t len = strlen(somestring);
    S[i] = (char*) malloc(len+1);
    S[i][len] = 0;
    memcpy(S[i], somestring,len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** S;

int main(void){
    int i = 0, x = 100;
    S = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * x);//t --> x

    while(i<x){
        S[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*1000000);
        if(S[i]==NULL){// check return of malloc
            perror("memory insufficient");
            return -1;
        }
        scanf("%s",S[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", S[0]);//fine
    printf("%c\n", S[0][0]);//fine
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not an allocation problem, just checked it. But I printed it and it works so the problem is in the access. Thanks for pointing that out to me!